# Autoconf Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: php, macos, fann, ampps

I need to install [FANN](https://github.com/bukka/php-fann) extension to AMPPS, so I need to use phpize util.
For using phpize I need autoconf.
I tried to install autoconf via MacPort and Brew, but a get errors.

```
$ sudo port install autoconf
```

return error

> Error: Port autoconf not found

And

```
$ brew install autoconf
```

return error

> ```
> Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local Could not symlink
> ```
>
> share/autoconf/Autom4te/C4che.pm Target
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/Autom4te/C4che.pm already exists. You may
>   want to remove it:   rm /usr/local/share/autoconf/Autom4te/C4che.pm
>
> To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:   brew link
>   --overwrite autoconf
>
> To list all files that would be deleted:   brew link --overwrite
>   --dry-run autoconf
>
> Possible conflicting files are:
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/Autom4te/C4che.pm
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/Autom4te/ChannelDefs.pm
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/Autom4te/Channels.pm
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/Autom4te/Configure_ac.pm
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/Autom4te/FileUtils.pm
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/Autom4te/General.pm
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/Autom4te/Getopt.pm
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/Autom4te/Request.pm
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/Autom4te/XFile.pm
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/INSTALL
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/autoconf.m4
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/autoconf.m4f
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/autoheader.m4
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/autoscan.m4
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/autotest.m4
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/autoupdate.m4
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/c.m4
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/erlang.m4
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/fortran.m4
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/functions.m4
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/general.m4
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/go.m4
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/headers.m4
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/lang.m4
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/libs.m4
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/oldnames.m4
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/programs.m4
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/specific.m4
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/status.m4
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autoconf/types.m4
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autom4te.cfg
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autoscan/autoscan.list
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autotest/autotest.m4
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autotest/autotest.m4f
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autotest/general.m4
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/autotest/specific.m4
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/m4sugar/foreach.m4
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/m4sugar/m4sh.m4
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/m4sugar/m4sh.m4f
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/m4sugar/m4sugar.m4
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/m4sugar/m4sugar.m4f
>   /usr/local/share/autoconf/m4sugar/version.m4
>   /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/autoconf-mode.el
>   /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/autoconf-mode.elc
>   /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/autotest-mode.el
>   /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/autotest-mode.elc
>   /usr/local/share/man/man1/autoconf.1
>   /usr/local/share/man/man1/autoheader.1
>   /usr/local/share/man/man1/autom4te.1
>   /usr/local/share/man/man1/autoreconf.1
>   /usr/local/share/man/man1/autoscan.1
>   /usr/local/share/man/man1/autoupdate.1
>   /usr/local/share/man/man1/config.guess.1
>   /usr/local/share/man/man1/config.sub.1
>   /usr/local/share/man/man1/ifnames.1

What I need to do to install autoconf? Or maybe you know other way to install FANN to AMPPS?

Comment: did you even try what that error suggests? `brew link --overwrite autoconf`

Comment: Yes, I get other error `Linking /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69... 
Error: Could not symlink share/autoconf/Autom4te/C4che.pm`

Comment: use `sudo` in front of the command...

Answer (score -1):

Error: Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew link`
You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root.
However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at
your own risk.

Comment: Did you found a solution yet? I am stuck ... @Андрей Сердюк